# base motion planner with OMPL

Tags: ros, navigation, ompl, ompl-planning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
I wanted to create motion plans for my robot base (and not for an arm) using OMPL (more specifically RRT). I have found the ompl_planner_base package, but I get an error from svn:

```
https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_cturtle/sandbox/ompl_planner_base' doesn't exist
```

Is there any tweak to use the arm_navigation stack to provide plans for a robot base (ideally integrated with the navigation stack)?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12922/base-motion-planner-with-ompl/) by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4402 on 2012-02-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This link
[http://answers.ros.org/question/587/sampling-based-planning-methods-for-2d-navigation] may be of help.

---

Originally posted by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) with karma: 660 on 2012-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2012-02-07**:
according to https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/changeset/50709 the repository has changed to https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_dturtle/sandbox/ompl_planner_base/ I will update the wiki

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2012-02-07**:
Thanks. Actually it is exactly what I wanted, but the repository from ompl_planner_base is not working: "404 not found"

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From what you describe, the [SBPL lattice planner](http://www.ros.org/wiki/sbpl_lattice_planner) is what you´re looking for. Note that in general, it´s not easily possible to use a arm_navigation planner for motion planning for a mobile base (or vice versa).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-02-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2012-02-09**:
it is not exactly what I wanted, but it is worth taking a look. thanks.

**Comment by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) on 2012-03-28**:
Actually, the planners used in the  arm_navigation stack (sampling-based) are not specific to arm planning. You can use them just fine for base planning. However, they are likely not going to be as fast as an A*-type planner, and won't give you optimality guarantees.